# Bind JavaScript scripts to their respective web pages

Tags: javascript, angularjs, exception, dependency-injection, module

I'm working on a large web application which has about 10K lines of JavaScript code (without taking into account the third-party libraries). In order to speed up page loading it has been decided to automatically concatenate every script file into a large script that gets loaded (and cached) on the client the first time the application is accessed. This poses a problem due to the fact that each page had its own script which contained all JavaScript required in (essentially) the same function.
Now if an error occurs in one of the scripts it is really hard to tell where that error came from, since everything is rolled into the same script which is added to each page, as opposed to using explicit `script` declarations in each page as was done before.
Is there a JavaScript pattern for solving this issue? I'm thinking of something similar to the AngularJS modules that can be bound to certain containers inside a web application's pages.
However, I would like a simple, custom, solution, as we're short on time and we don't have time to implement a framework in our application. It should apply certain scripts (modules) only to their respective pages and it should allow developers to explicitly declare any other scripts (modules) that certain scripts rely on.
Also, implementing an exception handling system to notify users (in the Firebug console, for example) from which module an exception originated (if the page's module relies on other modules) would be great.
Is there a common means of solving such issues in JavaScript (without relying on frameworks)?

Comment: For development, you can bundle the scripts but not minify them. Then when you get an error, you'll be able to see the actual code. For production use, well, it's better to not have exceptions at all :)

Comment: Yes, that is the way we do it, but it is still hard to track an error in one of the scripts (there are 10000 lines of code) if something goes wrong. If a developer makes a mistake in a script corresponding to a certain page then he might get errors in a totally different place, since everything is loaded on every page.

Comment: Take a look at [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) and [AMD/require.js](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html)

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution to your problem could be the use of js source maps. Many concat/minify/uglify tools directly support this feature, while most modern browsers are capable of interpreting them.

You would still serve a single JS file containing all your code (even if this is most likely not the best idea to handle such large amounts of code - largely depending on your overall architecture)

But your browsers developer tools are now able to show you the original file name and line number of an error/console output/etc.

You might most probably not serve the source map file in production.

A good point to get into js source maps is [this wiki](https://github.com/ryanseddon/source-map/wiki/Source-maps:-languages,-tools-and-other-info).